# std::copy for vector doesn't work properly

Tags: c++, algorithm, vector, stl, copy

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    vector<int> a{ 1, 2, 3 };
    copy(a.begin(), a.end(), back_inserter(a));
    for (const int& x : a)
        cout << x << ' ';
}
```

Output:

```
1 2 3 1 -572662307 -572662307
```

Expected output:

```
1 2 3 1 2 3
```

I have no idea why is this happening. What's is the reason for this behavior?

Comment: The iterators become invalid. So your program has undefined behavior.

Comment: `back_inserter` calls `push_back`  and `push_back` invalidated `begin/end`

Comment: You could potentially `reserve(size()*2)` first, but it would be relying on undefined behavior.

Comment: How does `push_back()` invalidates `begin/end`? As I understood, `back_inserter` changes `end` iterator and while `copy` was trying to copy, the range for copying is changed and therefore these strange numbers appeared. Am I right?

Comment: `back_inserter` returns `back_insert_iterator` and this iterator calls `push_back`. You can check the reference for [back_inserter](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/back_inserter)

Comment: @RussianStranger *How does push_back() invalidates begin/end* -- 
 [Read the documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/push_back).

Comment: See the section on [push_back](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/push_back) where it talks about iterator invalidation. It _might_ invalidate `begin` as well, but it'll _definitely_ invalidate `end`.

Comment: And, more importantly, `push_back` invalidates the iterator that `std::copy` is using to keep track of where it is in the input sequence. `std::copy` does something like `for (auto iter = first; iter != last; ++iter) ...`. If `push_back` causes reallocation, `iter` points out into space.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is that as the vector grows, iterators you provided are potentially invalidated. You can fix that by using `reserve`. It is, in general, a good idea to use `reserve` if you know the size in advance so there are fewer allocations going on:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>

int main() {
  std::vector<int> a{1, 2, 3};
  a.reserve(a.size() * 2);

  a.insert(a.end(), a.begin(), a.end());
}
```

Do note that `insert` is often better and simpler than `back_inserter`.

Answer (score 6):

In general your program has undefined behavior because the iterators can become invalid during adding new elements to the vector.

You have to reserve enough memory in the vector. For example

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>

int main() 
{
    std::vector<int> v = { 1, 2, 3 };

    v.reserve( 2 * v.size() );
    
    std::copy( std::begin( v ), std::end( v ), std::back_inserter( v ) );
    
    for ( const auto &item : v ) std::cout << item << ' ';
    std::cout << '\n';
    
    return 0;
}
```

If your compiler supports the C++ 17 Standard (in the C++ 14 Standard there is a requirement that the iterators that specify the copied range were not iterators of the vector itself) then you may use the method insert, For example

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <iterator>

int main() 
{
    std::vector<int> v = { 1, 2, 3 };

    v.insert( std::end( v ), std::begin( v ), std::end( v ) );

    for ( const auto &item : v ) std::cout << item << ' ';
    std::cout << '\n';
    
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Possible implementation of `copy` from [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/copy):

> ```
> template<class InputIt, class OutputIt>
> OutputIt copy(InputIt first, InputIt last, 
>               OutputIt d_first)
> {
>     while (first != last) {
>         *d_first++ = *first++;
>     }
>     return d_first;
> }
> ```

With a `back_inserter` `*first++` will call `push_back` on the vector. Calling `push_back` potentially invalidates all iterators when the vector needs to reallocate. Hence your code has undefined behavior.

Note that `back_inserter` is a little exotic. It violates the usual strict separation of iterators and container, because the iterator has to store a reference to the container. That alone does not explain the effect you see, but it is indication that one needs to be careful when the iterator actually does modify the container.